# PostgreSQL and Scala - Non-Blocking API

Tags: scala

I would like to know if here is any library that I could use to do asynchronous database calls? I'm using PostgreSQL as my database. I came to know about slick. Is that non-blocking? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Slick documentation [What is Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/introduction.html#what-is-slick)?

> Execution of database actions is done asynchronously, making Slick a perfect fit for your reactive applications based on Play and Akka.

Comment: I will give that a try. FRM seems to be the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Slick as mentioned by @Jean there is also [ScalikeJDBC-async](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc-async) build on top of [postgresql-async](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async).

Comment: So just to clarify, using slick library for my JDBS calls to postgresql, I'm already async. Why would I need postgresql-async?

Comment: Slick uses plain JDBC